# The Program still throws an InputMismatchException and exits even though its been caught

Tags: java, exception, inputmismatchexception

I am just learning Java and I'm struggling with Exception handling. I am trying to write a quick program that takes some inputs and exports them converted into different units.

I am using Scanner to take the input and I'm trying to protect against an InputMisatchException but despite putting a try-catch block around it to handle the exception it still exits. the code is bellow. Hope you can help! Thanks in advance.

````
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //init variables
    String name = "";
    int age = -1;
    int height_in_cm = -1;

    //Init Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Get the input from the user and save to the initiated variables above.
    System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    try{
    System.out.printf("Hey, %s. How old are you?: ", name);
    age = input.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.printf("Agh! Sorry %s. We were expecting a number made up of digits between 0-9. Try again for us? \n How old are you?: ", name);
        age = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print("And finally, what is your height in CM?: ");
    height_in_cm = input.nextInt();

    //close the scanner to protect from resource leaks.
    input.close();


  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the exception is that when the exception is thrown for the first time the Scanner (input) does not update its pointer, so the `input.nextInt()` in the catch block reads the same input as the `input.nextInt()` of the try block.

To resolve this, add `input.nextLine()` in the catch block before reading the int value.

```
 try{
        System.out.printf("Hey, %s. How old are you?: ", name);
        age = input.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.printf("Agh! Sorry %s. We were expecting a number made up of digits between 0-9. Try again for us? \n How old are you?: ", name);
        input.nextLine();
        age = input.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional try-catch around

```
height_in_cm = input.nextInt();
```

Or else you'll get another exception!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are catching the error in the catch block. Try to implement a loop for it. Also remember to clear the buffer using `input.next();` otherwise you will encounter infinite-loop

```
do
{
    try
    {
        System.out.printf("Hey, %s. How old are you?: ", name);
        age = input.nextInt();
        stop = true;
    } 
    catch (InputMismatchException e)
    {
        System.out.printf("Agh! Sorry %s. We were expecting a number made up of digits between 0-9. Try again for us? \n How old are you?: ", name);
        input.next(); // Clearing the buffer. This is important otherwise Infinite Loop will occur
    }
} while( !stop );
```